# Loop through pandas data frame to create a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame from which I'm trying to create a dictionary based on a users age, where age is the key and the data associated with it is the value. So lets say users with age 10 will be in a dictionary {Age:10, Data:[Pole, Carl]}

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utCnQ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Group by age, aggregate the names into a list, and convert the result into a dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Age": [10, 10, 3], "Data": ["Pole", "Carl", "Jack"], "Rating": [10, 5, 5]})
df.groupby("Age")["Data"].agg(list).to_dict()  # {3: ['Jack'], 10: ['Pole', 'Carl']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[10,10,3],'Data':['Paul','Carl','Jack']})
[{'Age':k,'Data':list(v)} for k, v in df.groupby(['Age']).agg(data=('Data','unique')).to_dict()['data'].items()]
```

Output:

[image]